# Django pagination + filter

Tags: django, url, pagination, django-filter

I have a problem when using pagination and filtering.
I'm using `django-filter` filtering and paginator in CBV(ListView).
Everything is working. The paginator wraps the box after filtering, the problem is in the buttons of the paginator in the template. When you press NEXT or PREV 
the filter is reset. I found a solution:

```
<span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}
     {% for key,value in request.GET.items %}
          {% ifnotequal key 'page' %}&{{ key }}={{ value }}{% endifnotequal %}
     {% endfor %}">Previous</a>
</span>
```

But this does not solve the problem completely, so I can send a request from my filter:

```
?item_title=&description=&ordering=&popular=&min_price=&max_price=&category_brands=11&category_brands=13
```

And since I have two category_brands= in url and this solution doesn't work because I can not have two identical keys. Please help me.

Comment: I think the problem is with the organization of your params: `?item_title=&description=&ordering=&popular=&min_price=&max_price=&category_brands=11&category_brands=13` . Search a bit related to this. The `=&` seems strange...

Comment: Hi, & - so it's kind of like pasting values ​​from the query field. 
if the value in the filter is ==> min_price=1&category_brands=13 and if not min_price=&category_brands

Comment: just the way I indicated does not fit here, maybe there is another solution, how to combine pagination with the filter, and that they do not overlap each other

Comment: I think you have to put values for your properties. E. g.: `item_title=some_value_here&description=another_value&ordering=some_value&...` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
//tamplate_tag

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_replace(context, **kwargs):
query = context['request'].GET.copy()

for kwarg in kwargs:
    try:
        query.pop(kwarg)
    except KeyError:
        pass

query.update(kwargs)

return mark_safe(query.urlencode())
```

in template:

```
{% load <your_templatetag_name> %}
...
<a href="?{% url_replace page=page_obj.previous_page_number %}">Previous</a>
...
<a href="?{% url_replace page=page_obj.next_page_number %}">Next</a>
```

It works for me.